# HTML/CSS Icons as fonts usage - Hover change of color

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm considering starting to use this technic of icons as fonts, as it seems pretty awesome.  But I can't seem to figure out how make it change colors on hover of the link.  Here is a jsfiddle for you to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/eNhUf/17/

As you will see, when you **hover** a text like "caution", the text goes to BLUE, and I would also like the icon/font to go to blue as well.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.caution.icon:hover:before{content:"\0021";color:green }
```

This will make caution icon go green when you hover the link, I'm sure you can customize the idea as you like! http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/eNhUf/24/

Answer (score 1):

Font icon libraries usually use pre-generated content to inject the icon into the element. This means that you need to target that area and set the color.

```
<p class="icon caution email">Email</p>
<style type="text/css">
   .icon.caution, .icon.caution:before { color:blue; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks matsko, For the normal state, I understand how to change the color. It's on mouseover state that I'm trying to figure out.  So if I hover "Email" the text "Emal" and the icon would go to BLUE.

Comment: You will need to mix and match the pseudo selectors. Something like .icon.caution:hover:before, .icon.caution:hover { ... } or just .icon.caution:hover { color:blue!important; }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.icon:hover, .icon:hover:before { color: blue; }
```